# WSL2 lan redirection issue when Docker installed

Tags: docker, redirect, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lan

My current setup is my laptop and desktop, they're connected in the same network. I do webdev so i code in my laptop and see the results in my desktop's browser. After installing docker i can no longer access my laptop's web servers that are being runned inside WSL2 directly, ONLY if they're running inside a Docker container.

This issue wasn't present in WSL1, which is:

If you install docker desktop on your windows machine and enable the new WSL2 integration it will mess your windows 'hosts' file (found at `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

Docker automatically adds the following:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.77 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.77 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

*Note that 192.168.1.77 is my laptop static IP which i set in my router*

My guess is that these inputs are redirecting my desktop's requests to docker, completely breaking directly access.
This is not ideal because i have to build a container for coding a simple react app which leads to alot of useless complexity

ps: I have tried the following entries in hosts file, no success:

```
192.168.1.77 localhost
```

also:

```
172.22.3.92 ubuntu.wsl    # managed by wsl2-host (service that creates a hostname for WSL2 ip)

192.168.1.77 ubuntu.wsl
```

The only workaround is to disable docker and clean hosts file, which isn't really what it suposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to ~/.wslconfig (win) or /etc/wsl.conf (wsl)

```
[network]
generateHosts = false
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunally :/
i can only listen to connections inside a docker container on WSL

Comment: Oops, you may need to write this in .wslconfig as well.  
`localhostForwarding=True` 
Also,
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504051131

Comment: still no luck... Please note that if i uninstall Docker desktop everything works again. I don't think is a port forwarding issue

Comment: Hmm, how about installing docker with WSL2 without WSL2 integration?